# How do I change my JDK version on Big Sur?

Tags: java, macos-big-sur

Now that I'm on Big Sur, I can't set my jdk anymore! I used to do this:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 15
```

Now it just responds like this:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 15
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Before Big Sur, this command would always respond with the jdk path for the version I specified. My `.bash_profile` file has these aliased defined:

```
alias j15="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 15`; java -version"
alias j12="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 12`; java -version"
alias j11="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`; java -version"
alias j10="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 10`; java -version"
alias j8="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_212`; java -version"
alias j7="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`; java -version"
j12
```

So it would start with Java 12, but I could just type `j15` and it would set my jdk to 15. But now none of them work. I can type any of them, but it stays at JDK 12. (I have different projects which require different JDK versions.)

Is there a better way to do this now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List all versions with Capital 'V':

`/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

Output on My machine:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    11.0.9 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 11" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_181 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

While selecting a specific version enclose it with quotes:

`/usr/libexec/java_home -v "11.0.9"`

Fix for setting or unsetting current JAVA_HOME is:

```sh
unset JAVA_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v "11.0.9")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why I now need the quotes, but it works. But it only works when JAVA_HOME isn't set. This makes it trickier to use, but I was able to get it to work.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz For what it's worth (and for posterity), you don't actually need quotes — the problem is that you now must `unset JAVA_HOME` before setting it each time